# Heroku package.json issue

Tags: reactjs, laravel, heroku, npm, package

Package.json :

```
    {
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
                    ...
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "axios": "^0.18",
            "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
            "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
            "cross-env": "^5.1",
            "jquery": "^3.2",
            "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
            "lodash": "^4.17.4",
            "popper.js": "^1.12",
            "react": "^16.2.0",
            "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
            "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
            "react-icons": "^3.2.2",
            "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
            "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
            "redux": "^4.0.0",
            "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
            "styled-components": "^4.0.2"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
        }
    }
```

After deploying laravel app (with react) im having error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react-redux"
```

Im having blank site with above error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku installs only production dependencies on deployment by default, so the ones that are listed under `dependencies` key of you `package.json` by running `npm install --production`.

Move dependencies that are crucial to your app running from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` and that should solve your problem.

`devDependencies` are meant for things that support you in development, but are not required for the production copy of your app to run, like testing modules, for example.